# WPF excel interop error.'Window' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Window' and 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Window'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, excel

I wrote a small programme to reade data from an excel file in wpf. But i an getting this error:
**'Window' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Window' and Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Window'.**

Why is it happening? My code is given below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace FileReader
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWb;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWsheet;
    private void excel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Config.xlsm", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            xlWsheet = (Worksheet)xlWb.Sheets["Startup"];
            Range xlRange = xlWsheet.UsedRange;
            for (int rownum = 0; rownum <= 31; rownum++)
            {
                xlRange = xlWsheet.Cells[rownum + 2, 24];
                d32[rownum] = xlRange.Value.ToString().Substring(2);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("File not found: C:\\Config.xlsm","File not found",MessageBoxButton.OK,MessageBoxImage.Warning);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in error - `Window` class exists in two namespaces you have used. So, you need to use ***fully qualified type name***.

Replace

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
```

with

```
public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window
```

---

Or you can use *shorthand syntax* where you can declare alias for namespace and use it  instead of fully qualified namespace.

```
using WPFWindow = System.Windows;

public partial class MainWindow : WPFWindow.Window
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :** you have imported following two namespaces having `Window` class

```
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

hence there is a ambiguity problem while using following statement

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
```

**Solution :** you can use `fully qualified name` of a class `Window` to avoid the ambiguity problem.

Try This:

```
public partial class MainWindow : System.Windows.Window
```